# How do I integrate global int/string variables into my ESP8266 website?

Tags: html, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I use my `NODEMCU ESP8266` to control my LED strip behind my couch. I have a web-server that posts the HTML with `server.send()` in every loop. Now I want the website to show the current state of the led stripe, but I can't just integrate the variables into the HTML code of the website because the server is obviously going to treat it like HTML instead of actually reading the variables.

```cpp
//a variable I use for the LEDs
int colorCode;

// thats in the handler function
String s = MAIN_page; //Read HTML contents
server.send(200, "text/html", s); //Send web page

// thats the website
const char MAIN_page[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html lang="de">
     ...website...
  </html>
)=====";
```

I just need a small hint as to how I can integrate variables like `int colorCode` into the HTML before it gets sent to the server with `server.send()`.

Comment: Well `colorCode` is not initialized so it would need to be initialized to something if you don't want just random garbage. But you would want to translate your variable value to a string then do string concatenation. This would require the string you are currently sending to be not `const` tho.

Comment: @bigwillydos thanks :) will look that up.
And ofc I initialize it in the code, just didnt post all that here :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar has been done by, e.g., the OpenEVSE hardware project, which [builds its JSON responses in Arduino strings](https://github.com/OpenEVSE/ESP8266_WiFi_v2.x/blob/e979a7497b3fc864d4d363cb476f869a55c33566/src/web_server.cpp#L177) (String JSON):

```cpp
  json += "{";
  json += "\"rssi\":"+String(WiFi.RSSI(i));
  json += ",\"hidden\":"+String(WiFi.isHidden(i)?"true":"false");
  json += "}";
```

You could do the same as long as `send()` receives the right type of string. It would involve dropping the `PROGMEM`, probably the `const`, and likely using a high-level string class for convenience. Note that there are several reasons OpenEVSE chooses to keep the [HTML static](https://github.com/OpenEVSE/ESP8266_WiFi_v2.x/blob/master/src/web_static/web_server.home.js.h):

1. AJAX lets their app be more responsive than one that must be reloaded every page, and
2. an ESP8266's limited memory goes much further when it does not need to build a whole webpage.

Practically speaking: program memory can store large strings, but they will not be dynamic. If the string is not known at compile time, then it will have to be assembled at run time, and RAM will be used to keep track of it. Building the webpage in a string makes sense *as long as the page is small and the variables few*.